# Eloquent model inheritance hierarchy

Tags: laravel, inheritance, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a case where 2 eloquent models should inherit properties from a User model, but the User itself should not exist as a standalone instance. (Mentors and Students, both inherit from User class). So what I'm currently doing is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

abstract class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the courses that the user has enrolled into
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Course', 'user_course', 'user_id', 'course_id');
    }
}

class Student extends User
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    /**
     * Get the mentors that the user has hired
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */

    public function mentors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }
}

class Mentor extends User
{
    protected $table = 'mentors';

    /**
     * Get a list of courses that a mentor is teaching
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */

    public function ownCourses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Course', 'mentor_course', 'mentor_id', 'course_id');
    }
}
```

I am wondering whether this is the correct to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: IMHO i see only problems with Auth. The current user is retrieved from the database by id, so you can authenticate only on one table: students or mentors.

Comment: @dparoli my intention is to make the Auth work on the Users table, and then return either a Student or a Mentor object. But I see what kind of problem could happen. Any other idea how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I will use a userable() polymorphic relation, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411585/different-user-types-laravel)  and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: @dparoli I checked the Entrust package but my issue with this approach is that I need to store data for the mentors that should not be stored for the students for example. (I could forget about normalization tho :D )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO I will use [polymorhic relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations):

Use three tables: `users`, `students` and `mentors`; in the `users` table add two fields: `userable_id` (*integer*), `userable_type` (*string*).

**User model**

```
class class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function userable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

**Student model**:

```
class Student extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'userable');
    }
```

**Mentor model**:

```
class Mentor extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'userable');
    }
```

Now `User::find($id)->userable` return a Student or a Mentor object depending on the value of the userable_type

I leave the others relations to you, I hope this helps.

Comment: Since I haven't used these before, can you show me an example usage?

Comment: For example, I have a repository with a function getById(); Based on the given id the function should either return a student or a mentor object. Do I call User::find($id) or?

Comment: User::find($id)->userable return a Student or a Mentor object depending on the value of the userable_type field

Comment: Thanks, everything makes sense now :)

Comment: one more question, if I am to create the user manually - how do I fill the userable and userable type? (I am doing the CRUD operations for these users and I am wondering how the create part will work)

Comment: first create student or mentor, second the linked user, i.e.: `$student->user()->create(['username'=>'foo'])`

Comment: What would the PK of the Mentor/Student table be? The id of the native user they belong to?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jQdmzUQa this is what I'm trying to do at the moment but It's unable to set the id

Comment: dont use save(), first create the $mentor, **save it in the database**, and only after create the user, i.e. `$mentor->user()->create(['username'=>'foo'])`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209674/polymorphic-relation-morphto-save-not-recognizing-custom-primary-key

Could this be why I'm getting this error?