# Polymorphic relation - morphTo save() not recognizing custom primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

User model:

```
public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Mentor model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\User', 'userable');
}
```

The student model looks the same as the mentor model.

The tables for Students and Mentors contain a custom PK called user_id which references the primary key on the users table.

So what I'm trying to do is the following:

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->first_name = 'Trajce';
    $user->last_name = 'Petkoski';
    $user->nickname = 'ads';
    $user->administrator = '0';
    $user->email = 'asd';
    $user->password = Hash::make('test');
    $user->save();

    $mentor = new Mentor();
    $mentor->user_id = $user->id;
    $mentor->save();

    $user->userable_id = $mentor->user_id;
    $mentor->user()->save($user);
```

However, on the Users table, userable_id is being set to 0 while userable_type value is set to the corret value. The issue here is that save() sets it to a predefined 0. Any idea what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: what version of Laravel you are using?

Comment: The latest one, 5.4

Answer (score 2):

Try this to add data to Polymorphic relation (morphOne):

**Migrations**:

```
// User
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('nickname');
    $table->integer('administrator');
    $table->string('email');
    // add these two for the relation to work
    $table->integer('userable_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('userable_type');
    //
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

// Mentor
Schema::create('mentors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**User Model**

```
public function userable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Mentor Model**

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->morphOne('App\Models\User', 'userable');
}
```

**Association Code:**

```
$mentor = new Mentor();
// this is important: first save mentor
$mentor->save();

$userdata = [
    'first_name' => 'Trajce',
    'last_name' => 'Petkoski',
    'nickname' => 'ads',
    'administrator' => 0,
    'email' => 'asd',
    'password' => Hash::make('test')
 ];

$mentor->user()->create($userdata);
```

This works like a charm in my Laravel 5.4 test installation

Comment: $table->increments('id');
The mentors table's PK should be the user's PK, if the PK is Id it works like a charm.

Comment: this is not the way polymorphic relations works. Have you tried? post an answer please I am curious to see the solution.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. It was a bug in Laravel's core code that got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function users() {
  return $this->morphMany('App\Models\User', 'userable');
}
```

Comment: It's a 1:1 relation