# How can I implement a "can be" relation in an ERD diagram?

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, laravel-5.6, erd

I'm building an ERD that I'll implement in Laravel.

I have three entities: `Hiker`, `HikeLeader` and social media `Influencer`.

A user can sign up as any of the above three types. However, a `Hiker` or `HikeLeader` might decide to become influencers in addition to their existing roles. So they switch a button on their profile and they become a `Hiker` and `Influencer` or `HikeLeader` and `Influencer`.

These are example attributes:

```
Hiker:
    profile_photo

HikeLeader:
    logo

Influencer:
    instagram_handle
```

This is what I have in mind for an ERD:

[ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl2KO.jpg)

The first part is easy as the `User` will have a `userable` method per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411585/different-user-types-laravel) question.

So the `User` will be like this:

```
User:
    id
    email
    password
    userable_id // this will be the id from the Hike, HikeLeader or Influencer tables.
    userable_type // this will be class type Hike, HikeLeader or Influencer.
```

If I factor in the option of opting to become an influencer:

```
Influencer:
    instagram_handle
    influencerable_id
    influencerable_type
```

This works great. However, it only works if existing users opt in to become influencers as the `influencerable_type` will be `Hiker` or `HikeLeader` but NOT when a new user signs up to become an `Influencer` and knows nothing about hiking. Unless an influencer object can morph to itself?