# How to get model of current logged in user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How i can get model of current logged in user? For example if there are two types of users in system staff and admin?
how would i know from which model user belongs?

```
Auth::user()->?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411585/different-user-types-laravel

Comment: maybe something like : if (Auth::user()->is_admin==true)

Comment: The solution is not straightforward. But there is a nice example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example

Comment: You should create a flag for this in user table.or use guard. auth()->guard('web')->user()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built in `get_class` method?

```
get_class(Auth::user())
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `instanceof`.

```
if (Auth::user() instanceof Admin) {
// DO something
}

if (Auth::user() instanceof Staff) {
// DO another
}
```